# I'd like to install Linux on a software RAID 1 array; I'm already running Vista 32-bit

Tags: windows, linux, raid

I'm currently using Windows Vista 32-bit on a RAID 1 array; I'm using the RAID provided by my motherboard so it's fakeRAID. Anyway, I'd like to do some C development under Linux but I'm not exactly sure how to go about installing it on a software RAID 1 array without messing up Windows. I'm not sure which Linux distro I'm going to install, so I'm hoping that information isn't important. Would I just resize my Windows partition and put Linux on the newly created partition?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: So, do I have to worry about where Linux will put its bootloader or will it manage that on its own?

Edit2: Oops, I didn't mean software RAID, I meant fakeRAID.

Comment: if you're using raid provided by your mobo it's hardware raid.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resize your Windows partition and install Linux, yes.

If you want to take one for a test drive first, you can install Ubuntu within Windows, which will put it on the same partition as Windows as if it were any installed application.